# React Native build is failing

Tags: c#, react-native

I'm trying to create a React Native for Windows project by following this guide:
https://microsoft.github.io/react-native-windows/docs/getting-started

When I try to run my app using `npx react-native run-windows` I get this error:

```
Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.34
√ Restoring NuGet packages
 √ Auto-linking...
Success: No auto-linking changes necessary. (7ms)
 √ Found Solution: C:\Users\alial\OneDrive\Desktop\Workshop\Visual Studio\SparrowRN\windows\SparrowRN.sln
 i Build configuration: Debug
 i Build platform: x64
 × Building Solution: C:\Users\alial\OneDrive\Desktop\Workshop\Visual Studio\SparrowRN\node_modules\react-native-...
 × Build failed with message 5:6>C:\Users\alial\OneDrive\Desktop\Workshop\Visual Studio\SparrowRN\node_modules\react-native-windows\PropertySheets\ManagedCodeGen\Microsoft.ReactNative.Managed.CodeGen.targets(78,5): error MSB3073: The command "C:\Users\alial\OneDrive\Desktop\Workshop\Visual Studio\SparrowRN\node_modules\react-native-windows\target\x64\Debug\Microsoft.ReactNative.Managed.CodeGen\publish\Microsoft.ReactNative.Managed.CodeGen.exe @C:\Users\alial\OneDrive\Desktop\Workshop\Visual Studio\SparrowRN\windows\SparrowRN\obj\x64\Debug\SparrowRN.ReactNativeCodeGenSparrowRN.ReactNativeCodeGen.rsp" exited with code 9009. [C:\Users\alial\OneDrive\Desktop\Workshop\Visual Studio\SparrowRN\windows\SparrowRN\SparrowRN.csproj]. Check your build configuration.
Command failed. Re-run the command with --logging for more information.
```

I tried running this command in powershell:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process -Force;
iex (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://aka.ms/rnw-vs2022-deps.ps1');
```

and it seems that I don't have any missing dependencies. Any suggestions?

Note: I did not follow the guid exactly. I added `--language=cs` to `npx react-native-windows-init --overwrite`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you're encountering suggests that there is an issue with the build configuration or a missing dependency in your React Native for Windows project. Here are a few suggestions to troubleshoot this problem:

Verify Build Configuration:
Double-check that your build configuration is set correctly. Make sure you are building the project in the desired configuration (e.g., Debug or Release) and platform (e.g., x64 or ARM). You can verify and change these settings in your Visual Studio solution.

Update Dependencies:
Ensure that you have the latest versions of all required dependencies. Try running the following command to update your project's dependencies:

```
npm install react-native-windows@latest
```

Clean and Rebuild:
Clean your project's build output and then rebuild it. You can do this from within Visual Studio or by running the following command in the project directory:

```
npx react-native-windows-clean
npx react-native run-windows
```

Check MSBuild Tools:
Confirm that you have the necessary MSBuild tools installed on your machine. The React Native for Windows documentation provides a list of required tools and their versions. Ensure that you have installed the correct versions or newer.

Update React Native CLI:
Ensure that you are using the latest version of the React Native CLI. You can update it globally by running:

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

Remove and Reinstall Node Modules:
Sometimes issues can arise due to conflicts or corruption in the installed node modules. Try removing the node_modules folder and reinstalling the dependencies:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Follow the Guide:
Although you mentioned not following the guide exactly, it's generally recommended to follow the official documentation and setup instructions closely. Ensure that you haven't missed any crucial steps or modifications specific to your project.

If none of the above solutions resolve the issue, it might be helpful to provide more context or specific details about your project setup and configuration. Additionally, you can try searching for similar issues on the React Native for Windows GitHub repository or posting a question there for further assistance.

Comment: Thank you very much kind stranger. It turned out to be a problem with React Native CLI.
Reinstalling it fixed the problem.

Have a nice day!